# Battery issue with iOS7 and iPhone4

Tags: iphone, battery

So, I have IOS7 installed in my iphone 4.

I first noticed this bug as follows:
When I get home around 18h I plug-in the computer, and at around 23h before going to bed it's already 100% for some time, phone is not even hot from charging anymore.
Before sleeping, unplug the computer, then I hold down the power button and slide the red banner to completely power it off.
Next day at around 8am when going out, I turn-on the iphone and the batery is at ~80%... WTF?

So after realising this issue was persistent, I tried some other tests... turn off wifi or 3g or both before sleeping, phone simply doesnt care, even in airplane mode the cellphone simply goes drunk and waste it's juice.
If I completely leave it off for more than 3 days, there's no way to turn it back on again withouth plugging to a computer or charger.
Can people post here and comfirm if this issue also hapens in other iPhones 4, 4s, 5, 5c and 5s?

Now, that's a serious deal breaker, cuz back in april 2012 (other IOS) I traveled abroad and left my iphone 4 in airplane mode for over a month cuz I had no place to charge it, and the batery withstand a month of alarm-clock and notes reading usage still with spare capacity.

Now I wonder, what exactly is iphone doing to drain the batery even after completely turn-off procedure...
iCloud synching? Or maybe some powered-off location tracking? <<----- This is serious!!!

I hoped someone would notice this and fix, but since now I can't find this issue not even on google.
And I have to travel again april 2014, I probably wont have electricity for quite some time again... Guess I will have to depend on paper and wirst-clock-alarm, oh my =(

Comment: Battery CycleCount: 449, DesignCapacity: 1420, FullChargeCapacity: 1336, Status: Success, I guess this means that the battery is kinda new, 5% health loss over 2 years, only a quarter of what apple claims.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many reports of older devices that run iOS 7 that get significantly less battery life. iPhone 5s and 5c aren't affected. iPhone 5 gets hit a little. iPhone 4S gets affected more. iPhone 4 would be getting hit the most! As for what will help, turn off location services and turn down screen brightness are good starts. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, but come on, completely shut-down an iPhone with 100% battery and have it drained in it's whole in 3 days? What the heck? I understand if the battery is drained with the phone sleeping in airplane mode… But after a complete power-off it makes no sense to me!